# Select dates from DB but showing only one in case of same data

Tags: php, sql

How to retrieve one time the arrival date of flight from a table even if other rows has the same date.
Here my code

```
$sql = "SELECT arrFlight FROM flights";
$ data = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
foreach($data as $date){
echo $date['arrFlight'] . </br>;
}
```

Here is the response

```
2019-02-20

2019-02-20

2019-01-18

2019-01-18

2019-02-10

2019-02-01

2019-01-21

2019-01-21

2019-02-18

2019-01-18

2019-02-05
```

Now how can I retrieve only one time the dates that has same value?

```
2019-02-20

2019-01-18

2019-02-10

2019-02-01

2019-01-21

2019-02-05
```

Comment: Hint:  `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use group by / distinct in sql.

```
$sql = "SELECT arrFlight FROM flights group by arrFlight";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT  arrFlight FROM flights";
```

OR

```
 $sql = "SELECT arrFlight FROM flights GROUP BY arrFlight";
```

Rather then

```
$sql = "SELECT arrFlight FROM flights";
```